# In Python, 0 == (1 or 0), returns False. Why doesn't it return True?

Tags: python, equality, boolean-logic

I'm trying to see if a function returns an integer who's value should be either a 1 or 0.

`0 == (1 or 0)`

0 is equal to 1 or 0, this sounds like it should be true, but it's not.

Why? And how to do what I'm looking to do correctly?

Answer (score 6):

`0 == (1 or 0)` is parsed as this tree:

```
  ==
 /  \
0    or
    /  \
   1    0
```

`1 or 0` results in `1`, because `or` returns the first truthy value of the two operands (and `1` is truthy).

Afterwards, we're left with `0 == 1`, which is obviously False.

What you *want* to do, is check whether `0` is one of those values which you can do through a sequence check: `0 in (0, 1)`

Answer (score 4):

`1 or 0` evaluates to 1, and since 0 is not equal to 1, the expression is false.

I suspect what you are trying to do is something like `0 == 0 or 1 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the brackets. Which means you are forcing precedence on it. so python will first evaluate the expression `1 or 0`  which is 1.  and then it will evaluate the next part,  `0 == 1`   which is false.